# How to consume a Restcall with angular 6?

Tags: rest, angular6

I am completely new to Angular 6.

I have a RestCall that I like to visualize in Angular 6.

> http://localhost:52126/api/Sudoku/GetDefaultSolution

Postman return following (correct) answer:

> "[{\"SudokuBoardId\":0,\"clusters\":[{\"ClusterId\":0,\"list\":[\"0, 0\",\"1, 0\",\"0, 1\",\"1, 1\"]},{\"ClusterId\":0,\"list\":[\"2, 0\",\"3, 0\",\"2, 1\",\"3, 1\"]},{\"ClusterId\":0,\"list\":[\"0, 2\",\"1, 2\",\"0, 3\",\"1, 3\"]},{\"ClusterId\":0,\"list\":[\"2, 2\",\"3, 2\",\"2, 3\",\"3, 3\"]}],\"boardValues\":[[1,3,2,4],[4,2,3,1],[2,1,4,3],[3,4,1,2]],\"xDimension\":4,\"yDimension\":4}]"

Now I like to show that in an Angular App. The html-site is shown correctly, but the rest-output not.
Here my code:

**sudokudata.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'sudokudata',
    templateUrl: './sudokudata.component.html'
})
export class SudokuDataComponent {
    public sudoku: Sudokus;

    constructor(http: Http, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
        http.get('http://localhost:52126/api/Sudoku/GetDefaultSolution').subscribe(result => {
            this.sudoku = result.json() as Sudokus;
        }, error => console.error(error));
    }
}

interface Sudokus {
    json:string;
}
```

**sudokudata.component.html:**

```
<h1>Sudoku showoff</h1>

<p>This component show one single Sudoku and its solution</p>

<p *ngIf="!sudoku"><em>Loading...</em></p>

<p>{{sudoku.json}}</p>

<table class='table' *ngIf="sudokus">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>JSON</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ sudoku.json }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Everything that is shown is:

> Sudoku showoff
>
> This component show one single Sudoku and its solution
>
> Loading...

So the “sudoku” is not filled at all? How do I will that variable with the Json.output?

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure about this

```
this.sudoku = result.json() as Sudokus;
```

but i am using response like this and its working

```
http.get('http://localhost:52126/api/Sudoku/GetDefaultSolution')
    .subscribe((result: Sudokus) => {
        this.sudoku = result;
    }, error => console.error(error));
```

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 6 you don't need to call `.json()` because by default the response will be parsed as JSON and converted to Javascript object for you by Angular.

So just replace `result.json()` by simply only `result`

Also you don't need `as Sudokus` you can let Angular know what should be the type of the returned response as follow:

First update your interface to match whatever is returned from the API e.g.

```
interface Sudokus { 
 [prop: string]: any;
}
```

Then use the Sudokus type when doing the API call as follow:

```
http.get<Sudokus[]>('http://localhost:52126/api/Sudoku/GetDefaultSolution').subscribe(result => {
            this.sudoku = result;
        }, error => console.error(error));
```

Notice the <> brackets on the `get` method.